# How can I close/quit my app in macOS SwiftUI life cycle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know how can I close or quit my app? also I have some code for closing my app, but the code does not looks modern and updated to SwiftUI, do we got some new and better one?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Work_Space_macOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

            VStack {

                Button("Close App") {
                    
                    // Do we have more SwifUI-ish code for closing App?
                    NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
                }
                
                Button("Quit App") {
                    // How can I quit the app?
                    
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To terminate the application:

```
NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
```

There are still many, many features of AppKit that SwiftUI doesn't support.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you should not terminate your app directly. Use this to trigger termination when the last window is closed by the user or closed programatically.

```
@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    ...

}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is your approach any better if we are on SwiftUI? I mean you are defining delegate which SwiftUI does not like it.

Comment: @swiftPunk this is Apple's guidance to ensure the necessary cleanup takes place.  SwiftUI does not seem to mind, I just asked him lol!

Comment: This does not work anymore with Xcode 14 / Ventura

Comment: @SébastienStormacq - seems to still work in my test with SwiftUI in Xcode 14.1/macOS 13

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI that is too simple. Just use

```
exit(0)
```

It will terminate the Application. and works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
NSApp.terminate(nil)
```

In some cases like when your app is an agent, you can't relay on windows as most of them are either closed or hidden. This will be the only way to terminate the app.